# Can I install iOS 6 on an iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is iOS 6 compatible with my iPhone 3GS model? The model number of my iPhone is A1303.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, in the Apple's [iOS 6 What's new](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/) page, the iPhone 3GS is listed with any kind of restrictions.